# Sorting a bubble chart by last name while displaying the full name in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a bit of code that produces a bubble chart. I masked the variable names for confidentiality.

```
p <- ggplot(mydata,aes(x = Company, y = FullName, size = SizeVariable))

p + geom_point(color='red4')+
scale_size(range=c(5,15))

[Redacted the scales and themes for simplicity]
```

I have an additional variable in the data for the last name. I would like to sort the plot that's produced alphabetically by the last name, but display the full name. Currently, the plot automatically sorts by FIRST name, which is creating some issues for our reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You can mutate the `SizeVariable` as a factor, and give levels in the order you want.

```
mydata <- mydata %>%
  mutate(SizeVariable_Factor = factor(SizeVariable, levels(SizeVariable_ordered_by_lastname))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Because the y-axis is set to the name and not the size variable, I still get the same issue. When I try to use your above code but on the Full Name variable, I get NA's for every record. Not sure why that is.

Comment: It's unlikely you'll get more specific feedback without a reproducible example.